# Running basic node.js on windows hosted site

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, express, hosting

I need some advice for getting a basic express app to work on my site. The site is hosted on Arvixe.com windows hosting. I can run code on my localhost and it works but as soon as I move it to the Arvixe site it is giving me a 404 error - file or directory not found.

At the root of my site I have a folder called node_modules that has express in it. I also have a app.js file and a web.config file.

This is the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <add value="app.js" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send("This would be some HTML");
});

app.get('/api', function(request, response) {
    response.send({name:"Raymond",age:40});
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

The only difference between the localhost version and this version is there is a web.config file and in app.js I changed app.listen to use PORT instead of a local port number. The only files I'm accessing should be app.js and express and they are both there.

I'm very new to node.js and express. Am I missing something about how these files communicate between one another or what is happening to stop my site from running? Is there a simple way I could debug things like this in the future?

Comment: Is this on their shared hosting or do you have a VPS?  If shared, did you have to ask them to install it or was it already there?

Comment: The node site is on their shared windows hosting. I had to ask them to install node. I also had a Linux shared hosting and had to install it myself. The Linux version was a much harder process to work with for me, but I am a windows user so I guess that's expected. I ended up switching my sites all over to windows and it has been a good experience ever since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to get this to work. I added this code to my web.config:

```
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="/">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I'm surprised this was necessary because app.js was set to the default document. Apparently Express requires rewriting the urls instead of using the default document tags.